# Links not displaying properly in ASP MVC3 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tweetsharp

I've implemented the solution explained in this post [How to get tweet's HTML with LinqToTwitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855347/how-to-get-tweets-html-with-linqtotwitter/7855858#7855858) but when I display my tweets the HTML links appear like this

```
<a class="inline" href="http://twitter.com/cgitosh" target="_blank">@cgitosh</a> And how are you?
```

instead of just showing @cgitosh And how are you? with @cgitosh linking to the twitter account.

What I'm I not doing right?

Razor code snipet:

```
@{var tweet = TwitterExtensions.Text2Html(item.Text);}
<div>@tweet</div>
```

So I basically pass the tweet text to the Text2HTML function which is explained in the link provided above which returns the tweet with links to the variable tweet which I then output in my view

Comment: Do you have the page up anywhere? If so, can you link to it? Would help to take a look.

Comment: I'm developing on local machine. which other way can I help clarify?

Comment: Can you post the razor snippet where you're calling the TextAsHTML helper?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the razor snippet. hope it's adequate

Comment: Absolutely. Answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@{var tweet = TwitterExtensions.Text2Html(item.Text);}
<div>@(new HtmlString(tweet))</div>
```

...and unless you're using tweet elsewhere, you could just do

```
<div>@(new HtmlString(TwitterExtensions.Text2Html(item.Text)))</div>
```

Razor by default HTML encodes strings, so you have to explicitly tell it to render it as markup. (See [here](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=2218).) Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. would never have found this out in a thousand years :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<div>@Html.Raw(tweet)</div>
```

The `Html.Raw` method will not HTML encode the output which is what Razor does by default.